# Expected value is invariant to invertible transformations

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $x$ be a continuous random variable with distribution $D$ and pdf $P(x)$ supported by $\mathbb{R}$. Let $T:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an increasing invertible transformation. We denote by $T \circ D$ the distribution of $T(x)$ for $x \sim D$. Let $c:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable function. Since $P(x)dx = P(y)dy$ for $y = T(x)$, we have:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_{x\sim D}[c(T(x))]  = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} c(T(x)) P(x) dx = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} c(y) P(y) dy = \mathbb{E}_{y \sim T \circ D}[c(y)]
\end{equation}

My question: is the equation $\mathbb{E}_{x\sim D}[c(T(x))] = \mathbb{E}_{y \sim T \circ D}[c(y)]$ true for similar conditions in the $m > 1$ dimensional case.

Comment: I fail to see how the 1D case holds. Can you please detail ?

Comment: Sorry. Abuse of notation. Used the term $d$ twice. Changed the notation of the given function $d$ to $c$.

Comment: I find your lower and upper-case usages unusual but I think you are asking if, with the random variables $X$ and $Y$ and functions $t(x)$ and $c(y)$ where $Y=t(X)$, whether $\mathbb E_X^{\,}[c(t(X))] = \mathbb E_Y^{\,}[c(Y)]$. Yes, providing the expectations exist

Comment: @Henry on what conditions does it work?

Comment: @tomerg: I am not sure I understand the new question. I said before that it works so long as the expectations exist.  An example where it would not work could be where $c(Y)$ had a Cauchy distribution.

Comment: @Henry Can you please put a reference? It will be highly appreciated. Thanks!